# SQL sentence get from table，have variable in sentence，can't execute

Tags: php, mysql, eval

I have a table save some sql sentence.

For example：

```
value:`select * from table where aa='".$test."'`

 <?php
      $test="bbb";
      $strsql=$row["sql"]; 
      echo $strsql;
      //result is :select * from table where aa='".$test."'
 ?>
```

but I want: `select * from table where aa='bbb'`

help me 
thanks!!

Comment: Please add some more details and/or give some more examples to explain your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should used explode function like

```
$test="bbb";
$data=explode("=",$strsql);
$new_query=$data[0]."='$test'"
```

You can used `eval()` function but i suppose you are new coder and `eval()` function is very dangerous.

As per PHP Manual

> Caution The eval() language construct is very dangerous because it
>   allows execution of arbitrary PHP code. Its use thus is discouraged.
>   If you have carefully verified that there is no other option than to
>   use this construct, pay special attention not to pass any user
>   provided data into it without properly validating it beforehand.

Comment: Why using `explode`? and not `eval`? I believe it can be done without the `explode` and `eval` is more elegant...

Comment: @DavidWinder i will agree with you. as my opinion james  is new coder and i know eval() is very dangerous and i think only good coder should used this function .as per php manual "Caution
The eval() language construct is very dangerous because it allows execution of arbitrary PHP code. Its use thus is discouraged. If you have carefully verified that there is no other option than to use this construct, pay special attention not to pass any user provided data into it without properly validating it beforehand."

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using [eval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php): (which evaluate a string as PHP code)

```
$test = "bbb";
$strsql = 'select * from table where aa=\'".$test."\''; // as $row["sql"];
eval("\$strsql = \"$strsql\";");
echo $strsql;
```

Comment: Beware using eval, especially if taking in unknown data as it is open to all sorts of injections.